# How could I put a function containing multiple parameters into hashmap value in Java?

Tags: java

I have tried to make it successful but I couldn't deal with it even though I've searched many things which is related to this problem on the internet and Stackoverflow.

So what I would like to do is like this.

```
    BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> mul = (a, b) -> a * b;

    Map<Character, IntUnaryOperator> commands = new HashMap<>();
    commands.put('*', (a, b) -> mul.apply(a, b) );
```

?
// commands.put('*', (a, b) ->{ return a * b;} ); <- Using lambda was impossible as well.

I would like to put a function, 'mul' into the value of hashmap, including recieveing
two parmeters. I've just started using Java and I tried to check and read documents but I couldn't find out the way to do this successfully.

I'd be glad if you could help me.
Thank you.

Comment: you have to replace `b` with a value, since `a` is passed in from the `IntUnaryOperator`'s `a` already (the `a ->` part), while `b` isn't found in that scope

Comment: Multiplication isn't a unary operator -- it is a binary operator, i.e. it has two arguments. I don't understand why you don't simply put `mul` in the `Map`?

Comment: You need to explain why "Using lambda was impossible".

Comment: @TrashCan I'm sorry to be mistaken. I have just edited it to (a, b) -> mul.apply(a, b)

Comment: @tgdavies The reason that I could see on IntelliJ about using lambda was impossible is here, 
Operator '*' cannot be applied to 'int', '<lambda parameter>'

Comment: I'm not familiar with BiFunction and IntUnaryOperator, but why not make your own functional interface?

Comment: See my comment above -- use IntBinaryOperator as the type of the value in your Map.

Comment: `IntUnaryOperator` doesn't accept 2 parameters, it accepts 1, hence the name **Unary**, `IntUnaryOperator operator = number -> number * 10`, if you want to accept 2 parameters, you have to change your `Map` to `Map<Character, IntBinaryOperator>`

Answer (score 0):

I would use a functional interface for this purpose.

```
import java.util.*;

interface Eval {
   int eval(int a, int b);
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Character, Eval> f = new HashMap<>();
        f.put('*', (a,b)->a*b);
        f.put('+', (a,b)->a+b);
        
        System.out.println(f.get('*').eval(4,5));
        System.out.println(f.get('+').eval(4,5));
    }
}
```

Output

```
20
9
```

Comment: That is identical to `java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator`.

Comment: You are right.  I never used it before.